# jQuery width method adds padding + margin to DOM

Tags: jquery

Why does setting an element's width using jQuery's `.width()` method does it automatically add padding and margin to the number and slaps that into the DOM? This behavior isn't described in the documentation and doesn't make sense as a default. I would have to get the margin and padding myself and subtract that from the number I actually want in order to make this method work as expected.

When you ask jQuery what the width of an element is it removes the padding and margin, that it just added mind you, and reports a false number... Not sure if its always behaved like this or changed recently.

```js
$("#cowboy-btn").width(110); // results in 128px in the DOM instead of 110px
//$("#cowboy-btn").width("110px"); // same result 128px instead of 110px

console.log($("#cowboy-btn").width()); // reports 110, but its NOT, its 128!!!!

console.log($("#cowboy-btn").css("width")); // finally some sanity with 128px
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- the width in the DOM should be 110px, NOT 128px.. -->
<button id="cowboy-btn">Howdy partna!</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
$("#cowboy-btn").width(110); // results in 128px in the DOM instead of 110px
//$("#cowboy-btn").width("110px"); // same result 128px instead of 110px

console.log($("#cowboy-btn").outerWidth(true)); // reports 110, but its NOT, its 128!!!!

console.log($("#cowboy-btn").css("width")); // finally some sanity with 128px
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- the width in the DOM should be 110px, NOT 128px.. -->
<button id="cowboy-btn">Howdy partna!</button>
```